# Searchkick, elasticsearch, text with '-' character

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm running a search which looks like this:

```
fields = %i[name^10 abbreviation^5 description]

::Record.search(q ? q : "*",
                fields: fields,
                match: :word_middle,
                per_page: max_per_page(per_page) || 30,
                page: page || 1,
                order: sort_clause,
                aggs: aggs,
                misspellings: {below: 5}
      )
```

A user ran a search for a record with a name along the lines of "THIS-THAT" and received no hits (there's a single THIS-THAT record in the database). Upon investigation I found that removing the `match :word_middle` from the expression above caused their desired result to appear. This will affect other searches, though, and so I can't do that.

The Rails development logs show this (amongst much other output):

```
{"query":"THISTHAT","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":20,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}}]}}
```

So, it appears that the "-" is removed during the query. Can anyone suggest what I might do about this?

Comment: I can only speak for the Elasticsearch: What most likely happens is that you are using the standard analyzer (that tokenizes on `-` and also removes that character). You might want to switch to the whitespace tokenizer if you want to keep the dash?
Though by default the same analyzer is used for indexing and searching, so that shouldn't really throw you off. Not sure what Searchkick is doing there behind the scenes

Comment: Thanks. I can see from using `debug: true` that it is using `"analyzer":"searchkick_word_search"`, FWIW, but no luck yet managing to change this.

Comment: Once created, you cannot change it any more. Not sure if this is done through an index template or explicitly at index creation by Searchkick

Comment: I was looking for a means to change it in the model definition before re-indexing, but couldn't find anything in the documentation that was successful.